# How to set exposure per-camera, instead of for the whole scene?

Tags: camera

I have several cameras that represent different views of the same scene and it would be handy to set the exposure on the CAMERA, instead of on the whole scene. Is there any way to do that without a plugin? If not, are there any good plugins for letting me control the view differently for each camera?

Background: I am making an architectural reproduction and it requires shots from various locations in and around the buildings. These shots have been carefully selected, and I need to re-render each shot from time-to-time (especially as the buildings are added/updated/changed), SO this means that I can't just move the camera from one place to another each time I need to render. It's important that they stay where they are, and that I'm able to re-render a particular view without a lot of fiddling, especially because we're doing some (non-scientific) comparisons between each version of each render. Consistency between renders makes that easier. Since some of the perspectives are inside the (unilluminated) structure, and some of the shots are outside, I have to use a different exposure level depending on where the camera is (these interiors don't have a lot of light and I can't add any). So if I could set the exposure level for the interior camera(s) higher and the exposure level for the exterior camera(s) lower, I would be able to just pick a camera and hit render, without having to keep track of what a good exposure value was for each one and fiddle with its settings.

Comment: You could save openEXR and use the compositor. But it's probably not what you are looking for, so you might need to explain a bit more about you final goal

Comment: I'll try to add more information to the question, but the part that's relevant is that I want to have multiple cameras in a scene, but use different exposure levels for each camera.

Comment: Hi :). I believe the [Photographer Addon](https://chafouin.gumroad.com/l/photographer5) can do that, haven't used it in a while though, so not sure. It has many parameters set *per camera* instead of per scene.

Comment: Are you going to render stills or animations? For stills, what I sometimes do as a workaround is using markers to switch between cameras. So let's say you have 5 cameras, then you can go to the _Timeline_ on frame 1, select camera 1 and hit `Ctrl`+`B` to bind the camera to a marker on that frame. Repeat that for frames/cameras 2, 3, 4 and 5. The _Exposure_ in the _Color Management_ can be animated by keyframes on each frame as you need it for the respective camera. Or you could use an _Exposure_ node in the _Compositor_ and animate it with keyfranes.

Comment: ...so instead of having to keep track of the exposure settings per camera, you just need to know on which frame which camera is set to render and instead of picking cameras and hit render, you pick certain frames and hit render.

Comment: I'm doing stills. Technically, your solution would work for me. Have a different camera active on each frame, and just animate the exposure so that it's correct for whatever camera is active on that frame. It's most of a solution, but I would still have to be careful about keeping track of which camera "belongs" to which frame... I wonder how hard it'd be to write a script for that...